# ts error in .js files when there is no typescript environment installed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues with ts error in my .js file when I don't have any typescript environment installed, both locally & globally. I tried something like `"javascript.validate.enable": false` but I don't want to use it, since it removes all error checks.

Here is my simple code:

```
//Part 1

function greeting() {
    return "Good Morning!";
}

let message = greeting;
message();
greeting();

//Part 2

function greeting() {
    return "Good Morning!";
}

function printMessage(anfunction) {
    console.log(anfunction());
}

printMessage(greeting);

//Part 3

function greeting() {
    return function () {
        return "Good Morning!";
    };
}

let anFunction = greeting();
let message = anFunction();
```

Here is .ts error:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.ts(2451)
let message: {
    (): string;
    (): string;
    (): () => string;
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would this work, regardless of if you have TS or JS installed? You're setting `message` to an object (`{}`) and then trying to call it. You can't call an object. EDIT: Nevermind, you don't call it

Comment: What do you mean with "part 1/2/3": Are those snippets from within the same file (and same scope)?

Comment: You can't redeclare a variable with the same name in the same scope in JavaScript: you have both `let message = greeting;` and `let message = anFunction();` this is not allowed.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I would be confident that they are given the error seems to be on line 2451! But yeah, need OP to confirm.

Comment: @phuzi I see the problem! Indeed, I guess this is a leftover from a course that provided this snippet. However, why does it show as ts error and not js error? (Because I don't use any ts environment here)

Comment: @OskarGrosser I should have mentioned: this is just a one file code snippet from a tutorial.

Comment: @ArtificialScientist I would normally expect the name of the file here but it's just showing `.ts` What is the name of the file that this code is contained in and how is it being run? But yeah, that error looks like a TypeScript error.

Comment: @phuzi the name of the file is 03Functions.js and it isn't called anywhere as it's just in a seperate folder (as sample codes). I use webpack for compiling the rest of the code, but there isn't any single local package that has typescript related stuff. And my global packages are only: npm, corepack & eslint.

Comment: Ah, we'd need to take a look at your webpack config then. It may be configured to "build" .js files as if they are TypeScript. If you want help with that though you should probably ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @phuzi it's actually very short:

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        port: 3000,
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: "development",
};

In-case you want to take a look.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with WebPack but if you ask another question you're more likely to get somebody who is. May be try and confirm that it's being built as TS first by adding a single line of TS to see if that causes issues. If there's no error then that confirms it's being built as TS.

Comment: @phuzi ah, that's fine. Thank you for your answers though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised it has nothing to do with TypeScript. I have ESLint plugin enabled, so it simply displays them as ts error...

Answer (score 0):

You use in Part3 `let message = ...`, so you redeclare a let-variable.
You can set message like `message = ...`

Comment: you have redeclared a variable defined by `let`. It has nothing to take with typescript.